# Custom google map embedded picture

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to create a custom google map just like [this](http://www.ward20.ca/neighbourhoods_detail.php?neighbourhood=entertainment_district).

How do I put my own map picture and erase rest of the google map?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
      #map_canvas { height: 100%; z-index: 0;}
      #gmnoprint {width: auto;}
</style>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
<title>my custom map</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
function CustomMapType() {
}
CustomMapType.prototype.tileSize = new google.maps.Size(256,256);
CustomMapType.prototype.maxZoom = 5;
CustomMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
    var div = ownerDocument.createElement('DIV');
    var baseURL = 'tiles/';
    baseURL +=zoom + '_' + coord.x + '-' + coord.y + '.png';
    div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
    div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
    div.style.backgroundColor = '#89919E';
    div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + baseURL + ')';
    return div;
};

CustomMapType.prototype.name = "Custom";
CustomMapType.prototype.alt = "Tile Coordinate Map Type";
var map;
var CustomMapType = new CustomMapType();
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
      minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 5,
    isPng: true,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(65.07,-56.08),     
      zoom: 3,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['custom', google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP],
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    }
  };
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
map.mapTypes.set('custom',CustomMapType);
map.setMapTypeId('custom');
}
</script>
</head> 
<body onload="initialize()"> 
<div id="map_canvas" style="background: #1B2D33;"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

use that code and put the tiles into the folder output =)

Comment: Which folder do you call "folder output"?